# Specifying file system on a bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, osdev, bios

I have a simple bootloader code to display a hello world message, and it works correctly when flashed into the boot sector from a usb drive, but when acessing files, the disk turns into RAW, and when formatting it to NTFS custom MBR goes away
Here is the code i wrote:

```
BITS    16
ORG     0x7c00
jmp start

start:
        call clear_screen
        mov ax,cs
        mov ds,ax
        mov si,msg

        call print

print:
        push ax
        cld
next:
        mov al,[si]
        cmp al,0
        je done
        call printchar
        inc si
        jmp next
done:
        jmp $

printchar:
        mov ah,0x0e
        int 0x10
        ret

clear_screen:
        mov ah, 0x07
        mov al, 0x00
        mov bh, 0x02 ; here goes the foreground color
        mov cx, 0x0000 
        mov dx, 0x184f
        int 0x10
        ret

msg:            db        "Hello World"
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw        0xAA55
```

On HXD i took a look at the MBR structure and found the following:
`EB 52 90 4E 54 46 53 20 20 20 20`
That translates to
`???NTFS????`
I tried pasting that into the first bytes of the bootloader and it didn't start, i also tried moving the code right and pasting this header into the empty space but nothing too
I am new to OSDev so this might seem like a stupid question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.